# dom Parser Error: PI must not start with xml

Tags: android, dom, xml-parsing

I tried to read the service url, which is in xml format. When I was try to parsing this xml, I got this error: I Searched for this, the problem with the xml starting header tag, i.e .

my xml out put from logcat:

```
09-25 09:09:37.134: I/System.out(408): ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
09-25 09:09:37.144: I/System.out(408): <ad2app>
09-25 09:09:37.144: I/System.out(408):     <mob_interstitial>
09-25 09:09:37.154: I/System.out(408):         <size> 
09-25 09:09:37.154: I/System.out(408):             <dimension>pixel</dimension>
09-25 09:09:37.154: I/System.out(408):             <width>320</width>
09-25 09:09:37.154: I/System.out(408):             <height>416</height>
09-25 09:09:37.154: I/System.out(408):         </size>
09-25 09:09:37.154: I/System.out(408):         <duration>
09-25 09:09:37.154: I/System.out(408):             <dimension>seconds</dimension>
09-25 09:09:37.154: I/System.out(408):             <d_number>5</d_number>
09-25 09:09:37.154: I/System.out(408):         </duration>
```

From above out put, the unnecessary symbols added. like this: `ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Now, how can I remove the unnecessary symbols from my xml to solve this problem.
Any  help...??

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved: I used replace method for xml string.
i.e: `String noHTMLString = xml.replaceAll("ï»¿","");`